# Merged headers in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-angular

Is the following format possible with ag-grid:

- Merged header with blank name
- Merged header with name in 2 lines ("Original Values")
- Parent header centered ("Header with children")

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling with this for quite a while, but i can not find a good solution. Anyway i figured out a solution (at least for my self).

In my case, the headers are dynamic. Only some headers have children.

Here is the solution:

1. Figure out how many rowspan should a header have

[image]

2. Apply class to header

In your columnDefs, use 'headerClass'

```
const rowSpanClass = .....  // This is calculated base on the data you have or set it static
columnDefs = { 
   ....
   ....
   headerClass: rowSpanClass, // In my case, if it is 2 rowspan, i call it 'header-row-span-2'
   ......
}
```

3. Apply style on the custom header class

   .header-row-span-2 {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50px;
   height: 100px;
   }

   .header-row-span-3 {
   position: fixed;
   top: 100px;
   height: 150px;
   }

The value of 'top' and 'height' need to be changed accordingly (ag-grid header height is 50px by default)

Comment: One good point is you don't need to be precise with "height" since the background is most probably empty.

Answer (score 1):

Just to share.  I think this is not possible using the headers in ag-grid.  So, instead, I set the headerheight to 0 and use the row cells to achieve the header format.

Comment: but then we loose all the rich features of the grid. Anyone with a solution? That's a good question they  ignored here too: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2491

Answer (score 1):

I know it is been too late for the answer but just to help another people know it.

Yes, it is possible with an updated version of ag-grid, please check it out.

```
var columnDefs = [ {
    headerName: 'Athlete Details',
    children: [
    {
        headerName: 'Athlete',
        field: 'athlete',
        width: 150,
        suppressSizeToFit: true,
        enableRowGroup: true,
        rowGroupIndex: 0,
    },
    {
        headerName: 'Age',
        field: 'age',
        width: 90,
        minwidth: 75,
        maxWidth: 100,
        enableRowGroup: true,
    }] 
}];
```

Comment: This example still creates a divided header for `Original Values` and thus not answering the question. Additionally, the plnkr is blank.

Answer (score 0):

You should just add the `spanHeaderHeight: true` to your column definition.

```
var columnDefs = [
    {
        headerName: 'Original Values',
        spanHeaderHeight: true,
        // ...
    },
    {
    headerName: 'Header with children',
    children: [
            // ...
        ],
    },
];
```